# How to change the background color of DateObject?

Tags: date-and-time, background

Recently I encountered a situation where I would like to distinguish between different `DateObject`s for a visual appearance for presentation.

For now, I am using

```
DateObject[...]
```

vs

```
Highlighted@DateObject[...]
```

[image]

But I would like to change the inside grey color of the `DateObject` blob rather than highlighting it from the outside.

Also, I would like them to be treated as different when performing algebra which is the case for highlighting in different colors.

Comment: Could you please add a more concrete example? You could style the following differently:  `Framed[Style[DateString@Today, White, Bold, FontFamily -> "Courier"], 
 RoundingRadius -> 2, Background -> Black]`

Comment: @Syed the question is about `DateObject` styling, not `String` styling. `DateObject` must have some internal functions to change it's blob appearance. Also `DateObject` to remain usable with its usual algebra after its background color change.

Answer (score 6):

Looking into the box structure of `DateObject` reveals that it is displayed as a `TemplateBox` with tag `"DateObject"`.

```
DateObject[] // ToBoxes
```

> `TemplateBox[{ ... }, "DateObject", Editable -> False]`

Therefore, the styling is set by the stylesheet, which you can access with `CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, "DateObject"}]`, and also change in the usual manner of [changing stylesheet](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/CreateANewStyleInAStylesheet.html). You can also set it programatically:

```
displayFunction = (TemplateBoxOptionsDisplayFunction /. 
     CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, 
       "DateObject"}]) /. (Background -> _) -> (Background -> Yellow);

SetOptions[SelectedNotebook[], 
   StyleDefinitions -> 
     Notebook[{Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]], 
               Cell[StyleData["DateObject"], TemplateBoxOptions -> {
        InterpretationFunction -> (#2 &), 
        DisplayFunction -> displayFunction}]}]];

DateObject[]
```

[image: DateObject]

To make color customizable, we can make a `color` wrapper around `DateObject` with custom styling.

```
displayFunction = (TemplateBoxOptionsDisplayFunction /. 
     CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, 
       "DateObject"}]) /. (Background -> _) -> (Background -> #3);
SetOptions[SelectedNotebook[], 
  StyleDefinitions -> 
   Notebook[{Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]], 
     Cell[StyleData["DateObjectColored"], 
      TemplateBoxOptions -> {InterpretationFunction -> (#2 &), 
        DisplayFunction -> displayFunction}]}]];

color /: MakeBoxes[
   dobj : color[DateObject[date_, gran_, cal_, props__], 
     OptionsPattern[{Background -> White}]], form_] := With[{
    fname = 
     System`DateObjectDump`prepareDateObjectBox[
      DateObject[date, gran, cal, props], form], 
    boxes = Block[{DateObject, TimeObject}, 
      MakeBoxes@DateObject[date, gran, cal, props]], 
    granbox = 
     System`DateObjectDump`getGranularityBoxes[date, gran, cal]
    },
   
   TemplateBox[{RowBox@fname, boxes, OptionValue[color, Background]}, 
    "DateObjectColored"]
   ];
```

We can now use this colored boxes for computation.

[image: Computation]